# How to set the variables of invocable method in unit test

Tags: apex, unit-test, list, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I have an invocable method with varables. I am stuck how to set these in unittest

Class

```
    public class or_service {    

    public class invoceVars{
        @InvocableVariable
        public id pIds;

        @InvocableVariable
        public String uid;
    }

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void Invoce(List<invoceVars> iVs) {

       ..
    } 
}
```

Unittest

```
 @isTest
private class or_serviceTest {

    private static testMethod void callFutureMethodPostProperty() {        
        Orbirental_Service__c  setting = new Orbirental_Service__c(ApiKey__c = '0000000000000',Url__c = 'http://test.com/'
                                                                   ,agencyUid__c = '0000-0000-0000-0000-0000');
        insert setting;

        Property__c prop = new Property__c(Name__c = 'test');
        insert prop;

        List<String> str = new List<string>{prop.id,prop.uid__c};
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new or_propertiesHttpMock());
        or_service.invoce(str);  
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this solution :

```
@isTest
private class or_serviceTest {

    private static testMethod void callFutureMethodPostProperty() {        
       Orbirental_Service__c  setting = new Orbirental_Service__c(ApiKey__c = 
      '0000000000000',Url__c = 'http://test.com/',agencyUid__c = '0000-0000- 
       0000-0000-0000');
       insert setting;

      Property__c prop = new Property__c(Name__c = 'test');
      insert prop;

      List<or_service.invoceVars> invoiceVariables = new List<or_service.invoceVars>();
    or_service.invoceVars invVar = new or_service.invoceVars();
     invVar.pIds = prop.id;
     invVar.uid = prop.uid__c;
     invoiceVariables.add(invVar);
     Test.startTest();
     Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new or_propertiesHttpMock());
     or_service.invoce(invoiceVariables);  
     Test.stopTest();
  }
}
```

Comment: @progati Thanks for the solution!. Please edit the following and I will accept the answer: invoiceVariables.add(invVar);